# VHDL ERROR: unexpected IDENTIFIER

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to create this code for a circuit, but it tells me there's an error.
The code is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity seq is
    port( CLK : in std_logic;
          GEN : in std_logic;
          INI : in std_logic;
          B : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
          Qo : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
          );
end seq;

architecture behavior of seq is

    signal Qo_pre: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    begin
        process (GEN, INI, CLK, B)
        begin
            if INI='1' then
               Qo <= B;
            elsif (INI='0' and GEN='1' and rising_edge(CLK)) then
               Qo(0)<= Qo_pre(1);
               Qo(1)<= Qo_pre(2);
               Qo(2)<= Qo_pre(3);
            end if;
        end process;

    Qo(3)<= not Qo_pre(3) when (INI='0' and GEN='1' and rising_edge(CLK) and (Qo_pre(3) xnor Qo_pre(0))='1')

end behavior;
```

The error that appears is:
Line 51. parse error, unexpected IDENTIFIER

help please :(

Comment: There are 33 lines in this source. How on earth do you expect help with line 51?

Comment: Please say which line is the line 51.

Comment: A `;` is missing at the end of assign to `Qo(3)`, but besides that the code passes OK.

Comment: There's an assumption in XST that you're following their [Design Flow](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/isehelp/ise_c_fpga_design_flow_overview.htm), synthesizing after behavioral simulation. If the parser can tell you that the identifier (the reserved word `end` in this case) is unexpected, it can show the value and provided a list of lexical elements that are acceptable. That they don't is subtle encouragement to get with the design flow, social engineering their customers. VHDL syntax errors can show up during analysis, semantic errors during elaboration and simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon, on the assignment before `end behavior;`. 
When I paste the code in my tool, it is on line 31.

[image]